# Disable the select glow for JButtons

Tags: java, swing, button, jbutton

I would like to know how I could disable the glow effect that appears when you hover over an `JButton` with the mouse cursor.

Comment: What 'glow'?  What PLAF are you using?  Can you provide a screenshot?  Most importantly, if it is part of the typical PLAF, why mess with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would like to know how I could disable the glow effect that appears
>   when you hover over an JButton with the mouse cursor.

```
JButton.setFocusable(false);
```

EDIT

```
MysticKiller 98 wrote that doesn't work,
```

then glow effect equals `JButton.setBorderPainted(false);`

```
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class MyButtonWithIcon extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Icon errorIcon = UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.errorIcon");
    private Icon infoIcon = UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.informationIcon");
    private Icon warnIcon = UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.warningIcon");

    public MyButtonWithIcon() {
        final JButton toggleButton = new JButton();
        toggleButton.setBorderPainted(false);
        //toggleButton.setBorder(null);
        //toggleButton.setFocusable(false);
        //toggleButton.setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
        //toggleButton.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        toggleButton.setIcon((errorIcon));
        toggleButton.setSelectedIcon(infoIcon);
        toggleButton.setRolloverIcon((infoIcon));
        toggleButton.setPressedIcon(warnIcon);
        toggleButton.setDisabledIcon(warnIcon);
        add(toggleButton);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MyButtonWithIcon t = new MyButtonWithIcon();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: `then glow effect equals JButton.setBorderPainted(false);` - that removes the border completely.

Comment: Answer of @camickr is the right method. It will only delete the rollover effect and not the border (`setBorderPainted()`).

Answer (score 7):

I think you are looking for:

```
button.setRolloverEnabled(false);
```